# In a custom dropdown, how to push down content below?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this custom dropdown menu, when I click on the top dropdown, I want to push down the dropdown menu below it.

Here is a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/dyvLNMr?editors=0110)** if it helps.

Currently, it starts like this:

[image: when closed]

and opens like this (overlaps the content below it):

[image]

But, when clicked I want it to look like this:

[image: when open]

**I know this has something to do with positioning, but I'm not sure where it should be applied.**

```js
for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper:not(.clearFilter)")) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger h6"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      if (this.getAttribute("data-year")) {
        current_year = this.dataset["year"];
        yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
      } else {
        current_story = this.dataset["type"];
        storyFilter(this.dataset["type"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#selectedFilter {
  color: #005fec;
}

.filter {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter__settings {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-top: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
  }
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}

.custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.custom__select-wrapper.clearFilter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__select-wrapper {
    padding: 0 2em;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper:first-child,
  .custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6 {
  padding: 20px 3px;
  color: #62668C;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__select-trigger {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6,
.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: .75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.custom__select-wrapper #selectedFilter {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom__options:before,
.custom__options:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 11px;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #005fec;
}

.custom__options.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.custom__select-trigger,
.custom__option {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005fec;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}


/* @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__select.open .custom__options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 15rem;
  }
} */

.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 15rem;
}

.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}


/* arrow */

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 8px;
  width: 5px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.1rem;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #005fec;
}

.arrow::after {
  left: -4.5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #005fec;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: -4.5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <div class="filter__settings">
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select story-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Story Type</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown story-selector" id="storyFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-type="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="news">News and Media</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="analysis">Analysis</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select year-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Year</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown year-selector" id="yearFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-year="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2021">2021</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using popover. But you should use an Accordion. You should check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp)

So what is the problem in your code? When your options comes to display it is floating over the screen. But it should contain the space

in the `.custom__options` class remove the `position: absolute` and add followig

```
display: none
```

It will hide the options.

Now in the `.custom__select.open .custom__options` do this

```
display: block;
```

In the arrow add this

```
top: 18px;
```

Comment: How would I apply something like that to what I already have?

Comment: Ok. So accordion is the concept I needed to apply, but the actual CSS was simple. This was a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks @moshfiqrony!

Answer (score 0):

I added a sample code here, I think you can get some Idea

*Sourse* :

1. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp
2. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm

```js
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;

            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "grid") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                panel.style.display = "grid";
                }
            });
            }
```

```css
  .accordion{
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
            
        }

        .accordion:after {
            content: '\2c4';
            color: #777;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .active:after {
        content: "\2c5";
        }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc; 
        }

        .panel {
            display: none;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            overflow: hidden;            
        }
        
        .custom__option:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: rgb(170, 204, 255);
        }

        .custom__option{
            margin-left: 35px;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="arrow"></div>
        <button class="accordion">Story Type</button>

            <div class="panel">
                <span class="custom__option selected" data-type="all">All</span>
                <span class="custom__option" data-type="news">News and Media</span>
                <span class="custom__option" data-type="analysis">Analysis</span>
                </div>

        <button class="accordion">Year</button>
                   
            <div class="panel">
                <span class="custom__option selected" data-year="all">All</span>
                <span class="custom__option" data-year="2021">2021</span>
                <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
            </div>
```